# Qt - How to change the direction of placeholder in a QLineEdit?

Tags: qt, placeholder, direction, qlineedit

I am using Qt 4.7.4 and my application language in RTL.
I have set the application layout to RightToLeft.
So everything is now right to left except placeholders in QLineEdit.

I tried setAlignment method 
but it changes the text and placeholder direction in reverse.
Then I tried setStylesheet but it does not work for

```
direction:rtl;
text-align:right;
unicode-bidi:embed;
```

I think it is a bug, Is there any fix?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft)` individually for each `QLineEdit` widget? I'm not saying it's going to work...

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks, I tried it but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changelog for version 4.7 reads as follows:

> QWidget::setLayoutDirection no longer affects the text layout
>     direction (Qt::LeftToRight or Qt::RightToLeft) of QTextEdit, QLineEdit
>     and widgets based on them. 
>  
>     The default text layout direction
>     (Qt::LayoutDirectionAuto) is now detected from keyboard layout and
>     language of the text (conforms to Unicode standards). 
>     To
>     programmatically force the text direction of a QTextEdit, you can
>     change the defaultTextOption of the QTextDocument associated with that
>     widget with a new QTextOption of different textDirection property. 
>     **For QLineEdit, the only way so far is sending a Qt::Key_Direction_L/R
>     keyboard event to that widget.**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I extended the QLineEdit and put the following code in it:     `QKeyEvent e(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Direction_R, 0);
QApplication::sendEvent(this, &e);` It works excellent.